# Rest path question

Tags: web-services, rest, resources

I have some code as a rest resource :

```
@GET
@Produces ( { "application/json" } )
@Path ("/some/{some}")
public JSONObject retrieveSome(@PathParam("some") final String some) {
    //body of the method
}
```

What does the `@Path ("/some/{some}")` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Path` annotation creates a URI template of sorts.  The `{some}` portion gives a name to that portion of the resource path.  So if the URI is `/some/1234` then `retrieveSome` will be invoked with the `some` parameter set to `1234`.  So the `@Path` annotation creates the template and the `@PathParam` annotation extracts a named portion of the template.  Read [@Path Annotation and URI Path Templates](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4867/6nga7f5nc?l=en&a=view) for more details.